# ffmpeg hue shift in tiff output

Tags: ffmpeg, colors, tiff

I'm using these commands to generate tiff and jpeg output from the same input mpeg2 file

> ffmpeg -ss 14 -i '../test/test-in.mpg' -q:v 3 -vframes 1 -aspect
>   4:3 -vf
>   "crop=22/23*in_w:22/23*in_h,yadif,scale=736:539,pad=736:552:0:7"
>   '../test/test-out.jpg'

and

> ffmpeg -ss 14 -i '../test/test-in.mpg' -vframes 1 -aspect 445:326
>   -vf "crop=22/23*in_w:22/23*in_h,yadif,scale=720:527" 
>   '../unit-test/out.tiff'

the tiffs are very purple/pinkish. the jpegs are sort of ok.

Q: what can be causing the color shift in the tiff output, and how could i prevent it ?

**The commandline output**

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i '../test/test.mpg' -vframes 1 -aspect 4:3 -vf "crop=21/23*in_w:21/23*in_h ,yadif,scale=720:540" -vstats_file /home/factory/log/20140630143715-mpg2stills.log '../test/test.tiff' 

ffmpeg version 1.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 26 2013 23:16:12 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mpeg @ 0xa4a1440] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000 microseconds
Input #0, mpeg, from '../test/test.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:30.62, start: 0.384000, bitrate: 7746 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, image2, to '../test/test.tiff':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: tiff, yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video -> tiff)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg2video @ 0xa4a3060] warning: first frame is no keyframe
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A    
video:563kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.003817%
```

**cropped version of input mpg (snapped by vlc)**

[image: cropped version of input mpg]

**cropped version of output tiff (converted to png for uploading)**

[image: cropped version of output tiff]

Comment: It could be a bug. Can you please try again with a more recent version? You can download a static build from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Its not that easy as per how its setup. I would try if I really believed its a bug :-)  Can you refer me something that makes you think so ? Have you seen this before, or read about it ?

Comment: The static builds can be run directly without any specific installation needed. You just run the file directly from the download directory. It doesn't overwrite any existing installation or cause compatibility issues. Experience tells me that *many* ffmpeg issues are solved by simply updating to the latest version. It wouldn't be the [first time there was a bug with tinted output](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2793). If the latest version does not work either, then we need to file a bug report anyway.

Comment: Hmok. Its not tinted though, its shifted.

Comment: I didn't say that was the exact same issue. Just that these kind of color conversion problems could happen.

Comment: The latest static build has the same problem. Not sure if I should submit a bug report. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the color space of the tiff image. ffmpeg copies the color space from the mpeg file, which was YUV encoded. exif data of the tiff file showed it was 'YCbCr', which is YUV.

The resulting tiff file could be viewed by some applications, but other applications (notably, photoshop) reported it broken. Not sure if that is a bug in ffmpeg. So I piped the result through imagemagick without any transformation, which seemed to repair the file.

However, imagemagick was assuming it was RGB, and set the exif data to RGB without actually changing the image data. Thats were the hue shift happens. Again, not sure if that is a bug in imagemagick.

jpeg had neither problems.

One proper solution is to specify, in the ffmpeg command, the pix_fmt to use. See
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options

So this did it:

```
ffmpeg -ss 14 -i '../test/test-in.mpg' -vframes 1 -aspect 445:326 -pix_fmt rgb24 -vf "crop=22/23*in_w:22/23*in_h,yadif,scale=720:527" '../unit-test/out.tiff'
```